# The null-pointer-constant is not specified using the NULL macro

Tags: c++, null

I am using a tool for analysing c++ code. My code looks something like this:

```
#define NULL 0

...
char * buff;
if (buff != NULL) { // -> error The null-pointer-constant is not specified using the NULL macro
 ...
}
```

Update: If I delete the #define null line I am getting the same error on this:

```
const int* var = 0;
```

Do you have any idea why this syntax doesn't work,
It is because NULL is defined as 0?

Thanks

Comment: Dont define NULL by yourself and use `nullptr` if in c++11.

Comment: Presumably, that's a complaint by the analysis tool, not a compilation error? Perhaps it wants you to use the definition of `NULL` from `<cstddef>` rather than defining your own (which you really shouldn't do anyway, if you include any standard headers). But we can only guess what the tool's author was thinking.

Comment: I updated my post: If i delete define NULL = 0, I get an error doing this const int* var = 0;

Comment: You should edit your post to update it, not add a comment !

Comment: Which tool analyser do you use ? Is it a *C* analyser (which may want `#define NULL ((void*)0)`) ?

Comment: I use QACPP and add in a file this '-SD "__null=0"'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for the `NULL` macro is implementation defined in C++.

With that in mind, it's reasonable that your static analysis tool is complaining about you using a value defined by yourself which may be wrong. ( even if it will work with basically all compilers )

That being said, if you have access to C++11, the preferred way is using the keyword `nullptr` instead of `NULL` as it solves most of the problems with the using `NULL` or `0`.

Example ( live code: http://ideone.com/EmahXG ):

```
int foo( int   );
int foo( int * );

foo( NULL    ); // Will call first overload if NULL is defined as 0
foo( nullptr ); // Will call second overload as nullptr is not implicitly convertable to non-pointer types.
```

Comment: Sounds like the tool is enforcing a style rule to make "the preferred way" into the only permitted way.